# How many terms need to be added to approximate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$ with an error less to $10^{-5}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, alternating-expression

> How many terms need to be added to approximate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$ with an error less to $10^{-5}$

So since this is an alternating series we know that $$|R_n|=|S-S_n|≤a_{n+1}$$
And so we know then that $$-\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}≤\frac{1}{10^5}≤\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}$$ isn't it? And from here then $$10^5≤(2n+2)!$$ which I'm doubtful if this is even correct, and that one would solve to be $n≥3$, but my book says it is $n≥4$. Is there anything wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: $10^5 \le (2n+2)!$ is right imo, but how does this become $n\ge3$? $8!=40320 < 10^5$

Comment: @CalvinKhor oh my bad. Now I realise, so everything else is correct?

Comment: Well, I assume $-\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}\frac{1}{10^5}≤\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}$ is a typo

Comment: @CalvinKhor now it's edited my bad. Is all the reasoning correct? Just to be sure

Comment: $7! < 10^5 < 9!.$

Comment: One error you've made is $|a_{n+1}| = \frac 1{(2n+3)!}$. There is no term with value $\frac 1{(2n+2)!}$. However, this doesn't change the result. Note that the value you are calculating is $\sin 1 \approx 0.841471$, while the sum of the series to $n = 3$ is $0.841468$, which is off by $< 4\times 10^{-6}$

Comment: @PaulSinclair wait that's true! And how does it not change the result? With $n≥3$ you *already* satisfy to be greater than $10^5$ (since with $n=3$ it is equal to $362880>10^5$)? I'm so confused now.

Comment: I meant it didn't change it from what you'd already deduced from your version. I.e., it still disagrees with the "official" answer, which is wrong.